# Analogue of "to the best of our knowledge"

Tags: expressions

I have seen the following formula when writing an academic article:

> **To the best of our knowledge**, this is the first work that shows how to
>   optimize a non-submodular function for ....

I like this construction in a paper, and I am wondering if there is a way to replace **"To the best of our knowledge"** by a similar expression that conveys a similar message, i.e. novelty, as far as one can tell from the literature.

Comment: *[AFAIK](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFAIK)* is used for that purpose quite frequently (:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you say "to the best of my/our knowledge," you're saying that "you think your statement is true, because it is based on what you know/believe, but you are not completely sure" [[Macmillan]](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/best_16#to-the-best-of-my-knowledge-belief).

So any phrase that expresses that lack of complete certainty that fits the context will do. In the context of an academic paper, you might say:

> **We believe** that this is the first work that shows how to optimize a non-submodular function...

Comment: +1, as "We believe" is an excellent replacement to the phrase in OP in scientific settings.

Answer (score 7):

What about ***"As far as I/we know"*** or ***"As far as I/we can tell"***

Comment: In conversation, "as far as we can tell" would be fine.  I'd avoid that form in an academic paper, however.

Comment: This is more of a variation, but I have heard it as ***"To the extent of our knowledge"***

Answer (score 2):

You may use *as far as we know*.